# Is there a near equivalent to sys/stat.h in boost::filesystem?

Tags: boost, stat, boost-filesystem

In particular, I would like to be able to access the user_id and group_id of a file. The closest equivalent I can find to stat struct is the file_status class but this doesn't appear to have the appropriate fields..

Any idea?
Cheers,
Ben.

Comment: check [How to get file permissions with c++ boost library?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9776050)

Comment: Thanks Charles, but its not the permissions that I'm after but the actual owner id and/or group id of the file. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) Boost::filesystem "provides facilities to manipulate files and directories, and the paths that identify them".

While getting information about user_id/group_id can be useful, but it can be non-portable and thus is omitted.