# recursive_directory_iterator throws exception

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I am using the boost iterator "recursive_directory_iterator" to recursively scan through a directory.  However, when the iterator runs into a directory for which my application does not have access, exception of type "boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error" is thrown, which halts the iterator and the program aborts.  Is there anyway I can instruct the iterator to skip over such directories.

I tried the code suggested at [Traversing a directory with boost::filesystem without throwing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970013/traversing-a-directory-with-boostfilesystem-without-throwing-exceptions)   However, it did nor work for me.  I am using boost version 1.49.

My code after following the suggestion (the best I could come up with), looks as follows:

```
void scand()
{
    boost::system::error_code ec, no_err;

    // Read dir contents recurs
    for (recursive_directory_iterator end, _path("/tmp", ec);
         _path != end; _path.increment(ec)) {

        if (ec != no_err) {
            _path.pop();
            continue;
        }
        cout << _path->path() << endl;
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: I updated the increment part of the for loop, and now I get a different error: ***** Internal Program Error - assertion (m_level > 0) failed in void boost::filesystem3::
detail::recur_dir_itr_imp::pop():
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp(818): pop() on recursive_directory_iterato
r with level < 1
Aborted

Comment: Apparently this is a known (yet to be fixed) bug: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4494

Comment: I have the same issue. Still not fixed in April 2015?

Answer (score 8):

This is a known bug in boost::filesystem (V3): https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4494. Depending on your needs you could use V2 of the library instead (it may even come with your compiler in the form of `std::tr2::filesystem`). Another option is to implement the recursive part yourself.

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
std::deque<boost::filesystem::path> directories {initialDir};
while(!directories.empty())
{
  boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dit(directories.front(), ec);
  directories.pop_front();
  while(dit != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator())
  {
    if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(dit->path(), ec))
    {
      directories.push_back(dit->path());
    }
    HandleFile(dit->path()); // <-- do something with the file
    ++dit;
  }
}
```

The above code is just to give a general idea, error checking among other things are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-catch blocks and if you catch boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error then you can skip the current iteration:

```
void scand()
{
   boost::system::error_code ec, no_err;

   // Read dir contents recurs
   recursive_directory_iterator end;
   _path("/tmp", ec);
   while (_path != end) {
      try
      {
        if (ec != no_err) {
         _path.pop();
          continue;
        }
       cout << _path->path() << endl;
    }
    catch(boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error e)
    {

    }
    _path++;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am newbie to C++, but how do use a try-catch block for a statement in a for loop.  I guess one option is to turn the for loop into a while loop.  I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

To build on [andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811/andreas-magnusson)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23135989/231306). If you have neither `std::experimental` v2 nor `boost`, try this. It'll skip over problematic folders.

```
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

    for(std::deque<fs::path> directories{{str_to<std::string>(path)}} ; ! directories.empty() ; directories.pop_front())
        try {
            for(fs::directory_iterator dit(directories.front()) ; dit != fs::directory_iterator() ; ++dit)
                if (fs::is_directory(dit->path()))
                    directories.push_back(dit->path());
                else if (fs::is_regular_file(dit->path()))
                    Handle(dit->path().string());
        }
        catch(...)
        {}
```